# SQL Server record chained

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

I'm working on SQL Server 2012
I have tickets with this information

```
Ticket No| Date | Closed
T001     | D1   | 
T002     | D2   |
T003     | D3   | Yes
T004     | D4   | Yes 
T005     | D5   |
T006     | D6   | Yes
```

I would like to group them by "case", the first ticket after a closing isopenning the "case" and all the following ones until the closing are part of the "case"

```
Case No | Ticket No| Date | Closed
C001    | T001     | D1   | 
C001    | T002     | D2   |
C001    | T003     | D3   | Yes
C002    | T004     | D4   | Yes 
C003    | T005     | D5   |
C003    | T006     | D6   | Yes
```

It's been hours i've been trying (using lag, rank, etc) but i can't find a way to do it. I an't find a way to generate the Case No as wanted
Do you have an idea ? Thanks a lot

Here is the query :

```
SELECT
    CONCAT('C' , ID_TICKET) As ID_CASE_TEMP
    ,ID_TICKET
    ,DT_TICKET
    ,IIF(IsNull(LAG(IsNull(LB_CLOSING,'No')) OVER (ORDER BY DT_TICKET),'Yes') = 'Yes','Yes','No') As LB_OPENNING
    ,IsNull(LB_CLOSING,'No') As LB_CLOSING
    ,LAG(ID_TICKET) OVER (ORDER BY DT_TICKET) As PREVIOUS_TICKET
    ,LAG(DT_TICKET) OVER (ORDER BY DT_TICKET) As PREVIOUS_TICKET_DATE
    ,LAG(IsNull(LB_CLOSING,'No')) OVER (ORDER BY DT_TICKET) As PREVIOUS_TICKET_CLOSING
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DT_TICKET) As CD_ROW_NUMBER
FROM 
    TICKETS
```

Comment: Please post your attempt to solve this using LAG.

Comment: Are you order by `Date` or by `Ticket No`? If you can't define an order, Sql Server will not guarantee a consistent result for the "first" record after a closed ticket.

Comment: where's your query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it using `LAG` window function

```
SELECT 'C' + RIGHT(Concat('00', 1+Sum(CASE WHEN prev_val = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                                        OVER (ORDER BY [date])), 3) AS [Case No], 
       [Ticket No],
       [Date],
       [Closed]
FROM   (SELECT *, Lag(closed) OVER( ORDER BY [date]) AS prev_val 
        FROM   table1) a
```

- **[Live Demo](http://rextester.com/XHFGEC12503)**

Comment: I didn't think about the sum over... Thanks a lot!